# styled-components with Typescript throws me unknow errors when passing props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

#### Background:

I'm doing my first steps with *Typescript-React-styledComponents*,

and I'm trying this simple case where I'm passing a `size` prop via a parent component, which will set the font-size of the child component.

**EDITED:**

#### Error:

**ts** throws me this:

```
Property 'size' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<ThemedOuterStyledProps<DetailedHTMLProps...'.
```

#### Questions:

1. I noticed `size` might be a problematic prop name, cuz I don't get any error on the other props. do you know why?
2. more general question - what am I missing?

#### Code:

**Parent Component**

```
<Parent>
   <Child text="Red Bikini" color='red' size={2}/>
</Parent>
```

**Child Component**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

//EDITED
interface headerSizeType {
    1: string;
    2: string;
    3: string;
    4: string;
    5: string;
    6: string;
}

const size: headerSizeType = {
    1: '2em',
    2: '1.5em',
    3: '1.17em',
    4: '1em',
    5: '.83em',
    6: '.67em'
}

interface ChildProps {
    text: string;
    size?: number;
    color?: string;
    style?: any;

    children?: React.ReactChildren;
    className?: string;
}

const ChildStyle = styled.h2`
    display: inline-block;
    color: ${(props: any) => props.color || 'black'};
    font-size: ${props => size[props.size] || 'black'};  //1st Error here
`;

const Child= (props: ChildProps): JSX.Element => {
    console.log(props.color)
    return (
        <ChildStyle color={props.color} size={props.size}>  //2nd Error here
            { props.text }
        </ChildStyle>
    );
};


export default Title;
```

Comment: `const size: any = {...}`... what would possess you to write something so terrible?

Comment: @AluanHaddad
I'm new, so you might see some terrible stuff here :)
I edited the code and I'd be happy to hear what's wrong, and what is the correct way

Comment: Gotcha. Type annotations are optional. Write `const size = {...}` and the language will infer a rich, well checked type for you. Using `any` there completely defeats the purpose of the language.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, though I didnt master understanding the issue :)

but I temporarly fixed it by casting the styled-component as any, like so:

```
const ChildStyle = styled.h2`
    display: inline-block;
    color: ${(props: any): string => props.color || 'black'};
    font-size: ${(props:any): any => headerSizes[props.size] || 'black'};
` as any;
```

I know casting ***any*** types arent good practice, and that's why it's a temporary solution.

I heard there's a Theme Object within styled-component, that gives you a more nice and clean solution for this.

**EDITED:**

another solution for types of styled-components types:

https://github.com/jacob-ebey/styled-components-ts

Answer (score 1):

You should specify prop types for your styled component like so:

```
type MyStyledProps = {
    color?: string;
    size?: string;
}

const ChildStyle = styled.h2<StyledComponent<'h2', any, MyStyledProps, never>>`
    display: inline-block;
    color: ${(props) => props.color || 'black'};
    font-size: ${props => size[props.size] || 'black'};
`;
```

Then your errors should go away.